# Input doesnt go all the way down to the children

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a question about this code:

```
    public class Musician {
        private String name;
        public String instrument;
        public Musician(String name, String instrument){
          this.name= name;
          this.instrument= instrument;
        }


        public String getInstrument() {
            return instrument; 
            }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
            }

        private String getClassName(){
            return "Musician ";
        }

        public void play(){
           System.out.println("[M] "+getClassName() + " plays music.");
        }

        public void printInfo(){
          play();
          System.out.println("[M] Class name: "+ getClassName());
          System.out.println("[M] Instrument: "+ getInstrument());
        }
    }

    public class RockMusician extends Musician{
        public String instrument;

        public RockMusician(String name, String instrument) {
            super(name, instrument);
            this.instrument= instrument + " and drums";
         }

        public String getClassName(){
            return " RockMusician ";
            }

        public void play(){
            System.out.println("[RM] "+ getClassName() + getName() + " breaks his "+ super.getInstrument() + "!");
        }
    }


public class IsraelyRockMusician extends RockMusician {
      public IsraelyRockMusician(String name, String instrument) {
            super(name, instrument);
           }
        public String getInstrument() {
            return instrument;
            }
        public String getName(){
            return super.getName() + " the king";
            }
        public String getClassName() {
            return " IsraelyRockMusician ";
            }


}

public class Testing {
        public static void func(Musician m){
                System.out.println("I've got a musician!");
        }
        public static void func(RockMusician m){
                System.out.println("I've got a rock musician!");
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Musician m3 = new IsraelyRockMusician("Chanoch", "guitar");
            m3.printInfo();
        }
}
```

I have IsraeliRockMusician who inherits RockMusician who Inherits Musician,
I then make a Musician m3 with the name "chanoch" and instrument "guitar"

and I active the method, print Info,
because the printInfo is in the father -> RockMusician which contains 3 methods on itself-> play(),getClassName(),and getInstrument(),

my question is, when the method showinfo runs, play is going all the way to the overwriten method and prints "[RM]  IsraelyRockMusician Chanoch the king breaks his guitar!",
now this is fine, but the next line is "[M] Class name: Musician ", which means the getClassName was given "Musician" and Im asking why its not "IsraeliRockMusician" since the method was overwritten.

I'm sorry if the question is a bit hazey.

Comment: Your `getClassName` method in `Musician` is `private`, which means it can't be overridden. You should make it at least `protected`.

Comment: @JonSkeet ahhh I see, it was a question for an output, I guess it was made that way on purpose, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the method of the base class has private access.

```
private String getClassName(){
        return "Musician ";
    }
```

Change it to public/protected so you can override it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a function where you hardcode the class name, you should use the following:

```
public  class Foo {
    public void printClassName() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

This way, if you change your class name, you don't need to update the method that you've written. One caveat to this is if you run an obfuscation tool against your code, the class name may be replaced with random characters. In that case, you can create a const string in your class and refer to that instead.